# Как настроить MAMP и PhpStorm?

Tags: веб-программирование, phpstorm, macos, mamp

Всем привет! Впервые установил MAMP, в качестве Document Root указал директорию PhpstormProjects.
В результате - со стартовой страницы MAMP сайты открываются, а из самого редактора по-прежнему нет (502 Bad Gateway).
Соответственно, я не могу вотчить изменения и т.д. поскольку эти процессы идут через  среду разработки.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, какие настройки пропустил?

Comment: у вас mac os зачем вам там mamp :-(

Comment: Так посоветуйте как лучше сделать, буду очень признателен?

Comment: Разве у вас нет гугла? Мож ну нафик это программирование ? Ставьте apache\nginx, SQL, php а чтоб это всё было удобней ставить пользуйтесь homebrew

Comment: не поверите, но мне данный вариант не подходит. мне нужно что-то максимально простое. так как я вообще занимаюсь фронтом, и мне просто нужно чтобы открывался файл index.php и чтобы фунциклировала формочка обратной связи, максимум еще require/include. Нафига мне устанавливать и конфигурировать сервер вручную?

Comment: Та если вы фронтенд то зачем вобще вам phpstorm? для фронта я думал webstorm нет?

Comment: мне нужны некоторые функции php, как я написал выше. у меня из под MAMP все летает нормально. но в IDE изменения отслеживаются с помощью gulp и он же открывает и релодит сайт. Вот тут-то и вылезает ошибка, как будто сервера нет.

Comment: Ну в гулпе настройте прокси для вашего апи

Comment: вот это наконец сработало, благодарю:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможный вариант решения вашей проблемы был найден мною за 1 минуту. Проверь вот это видео:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqHWhaPOfos

Comment: ну и скорость, спасибо:)

Comment: @coderxx я сам в том же редакторе работаю) Знаю где и что искать

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен указанием прокси-сервера в конфигурации gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
browserSync({
proxy: "http://localhost:8888/website/app/",
notify: false,
browser: 'google chrome',
})
});
```